# Gnu as suffix or opperand error

Tags: c, gcc, inline, gnu-assembler

I am getting a suffix or operand error when I compile an old source code. It is generated from an inline assemble code.

```
ltr (unsigned val)

asm 

    ("ltr %%eax /n/t"
     :
     : "a"  (val)
);
```

I have read a lot of web pages/forums to find the syntax error but everything tell me the code is correct. 
I am using gcc 4.4.1 on Mandriva 10 operating system

Answer (score 0):

Use backslash to end the line.

Secondly it requires 16-bit argument, i.e:

```
("ltr %%ax \n\t"
```

Or from memory:

```
("ltr (%%eax) \n\t"
```

Comment: Thirdly there's no reason to use \n\t at all with a single line of asm.  Fourthly, there's no need to force the use of eax since ltr supports any 16 bit register or even memory, so perhaps something like `asm ("ltr %w0" : : "qm" (val));`.  Lastly (and probably most importantly), ltr is only usable inside the kernel.  Unless you are writing an operating system or a device driver (which I doubt is what the OP is trying to do), it's not going to work.